# Fixed Header and Side Navigation Issue

Tags: css, html

I am building a page with fixed 100% height side navigation floated to left, and content wrapper floated to right. The nav element has fixed width 300px and the wrapper is responsive and takes all the width after the nav block. 
My issue is that I want to make the header to be fixed on top as well, however once I change its position to fixed it stretches to whole the page not to the wrapper width. Could you please navigate what can I use to do this. Please see the code below. Thanks.

HTML

```
<body>
    <nav>
    </nav>
    <div id="wrapper">
        <header>
        </header>
        <main>  
            <section>
            </section>
            <section>
            </section>
            <section>
            </section>
        </main>
        <footer>
        </footer>
    </div>
</body>
```

CSS

```
header{
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 30px;
    line-height: 30px;
    background: #fff;
}
#wrapper{
    padding-left: 300px;
    float: right;
}
nav{
    top: 0;
    width: 300px;
    min-height: 600px;
    height: 100%;
    position: fixed !important;
    float: left;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, this is probably what you're trying to get.

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/khhtbf60/

```
html {
    height: 100%;
}
body {
    margin: 0;
    min-height: 100%;
}
header {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 30px;
    background: gold;
}
nav {
    position: fixed;
    top: 30px;
    left: 0;
    width: 300px;
    height: 100%;
    background: pink;
}
#wrapper {
    padding-top: 30px;
    padding-left: 300px;
}
```

**EDIT DEMO 2:** http://jsfiddle.net/khhtbf60/2/ (this is the correct layout for what OP asked)

```
html {
    height: 100%;
}
body {
    margin: 0;
    min-height: 100%;
}
header {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 300px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 30px;
    background: gold;
    text-align: right; /*added*/
    padding-right: 300px; /*added*/
    box-sizing: border-box; /*added*/
}
nav {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 300px;
    height: 100%;
    background: pink;
}
#wrapper {
    padding-top: 30px;
    padding-left: 300px;
}
```

Comment: Yes I have also tried that way, but if you try to change the text-align to right to the header element you will see that some part isn't seen..

Comment: Thanks sdcr, this is exactly what I wanted :) As you were first who found the solution please post you answer and I will mark it as a right one :) Thanks I lot.

Comment: @EmilGurbanov LOL, you are commenting under my answer!

Comment: Hahaha, sorry, I am so happy with the solution that I did not notice this :))))

Answer (score 1):

Add the attribute `data-role` to your header div tag.

Example:

```
<div id="header" data-role="header">
```

And in order for it to know what 100% is on the width, change wrapper to:

```
#wrapper{
    width:100%; //or desired width
    height:100%; //or desired height
    padding-left: 300px;
    float: right;
}
```

Which in your case would be 300px, although it's preferred to use %.

Comment: Thanks for answer, but adding the width: 100% to the wrapper also stretches it to the whole page

Comment: If I change the header position to relative it perfectly fits to the wrapper, but once I change it to fixed it stretches

Comment: you at the data-role to fix the head and use relative to position it with CSS, relative should work. if not, get a jsfiddle and show me your problem.

Comment: here the jsfiddle, the thing is I need the header to be in the wrapper container no to whole page width https://jsfiddle.net/zzgL3ks5/1/

Comment: Bradley Wilson thanks for you answer and efforts to help, your answer also works, but the solution given by @sdcr is best in my case :) thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Give the wrapper a width.

```
#wrapper{
    padding-left: 300px;/*change accordingly*/
}
```

**EDIT:**
[Fiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/acL5xL3c/2/)

Comment: works only with empty header, once I add text with the text-align: right value it disappears somewhere :)